# Suppose the quotient group G/C is cyclic and generated by element Ca of G/C. Prove for any two elements x,y∈G that xy=yx.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Suppose the quotient group $G/C$ is cyclic and generated by element $Ca$ of $G/C$.
Prove for any two elements $x,y \in G$ that $xy=yx$.**

I am having trouble formulating a proof. In a preceding problem I was able to prove that for every $x \in G$ there is some integer $m$ such that $x=ca^m$ which I am guessing I can use to write $y=c'a^n$. Where would I go from here?

Comment: Is $C$ anything special? If $C$ is the center, then $cg = gc$ and $c'g = gc'$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: Ahh sorry I forgot to add that! C is the center of the group G.

Comment: So multiply $xy=(ca^m)(c'a^n)$ that seems a natural way to start. Then use properties of the center.